# Debug Java Card applets and understand the cause of exception

Tags: applet, javacard, sim-toolkit

I'm going to develop java SIM toolkit applets.
One of my difficulties is when I have an exception in my code I don't know how to understand what is the exception?

```
try {
        reg.initMenuEntry(MenuItem1, (short) 0, (short) MenuItem1.length, PRO_CMD_DISPLAY_TEXT, false, (byte) 0, (short) 0);
} catch (Throwable t) {

}
```

E.g. in above statement if  an exception happens, I don't know how to handle the exception and understand what is the cause of exception?

P.s. Is catching `Throwable` a good idea (instead of exception)? I tried to catch `Throwable` since it is parent of `Exception` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Some JavaCard platforms come along with a debugger, but this is mostly depending on the vendor, so you have to contact your supplier/vendor.

For some easy lightweight debugging, you can catch **Exception** and compare this with the different specific Exceptions provided by the documentation and throw specific **ISOException** errors, in that way if it crashes you don't always get `0x6f00`, but you could throw `0x6f01` for **OutofBoundsException**, `0x6f02` for **NullPointerException** and so on...

Comment: The problem is that exceptions are happening during runtime on the phone. So I don't know how to check the error code and the reason. Are there any simulators or IDEs specific for this?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, it's mostly vendor specific. Can you simulate the commands in a shell?

Comment: @I've tried using Wojtek but it is not working like a real phone. It skip exceptions and goes on while phone fails to run some commands.

Comment: @VSB my two cents. I use either jCardSim or Oracle's JavaCard Development Kit Simulator. Of course you have to avoid using proprietary algorithms that only your vendor supports